# C++ API performance issue with tree structure

Tags: c#, c++, api, tree, shared-memory

I'm programming an API for a C++ simulation framework. And I want to use this API for example in C#. But I am having a performance issue with getting the positions of all the characters in the simulation. I try to give you an extensive explanation how this framework works.

There is a simulator class:

```
class Simulator
{
  /// A list of the characters that are currently in the simulation.
  std::vector<Character> characters;
  /// A list of the path planning results for the characters currently in the simulation.
  std::vector<PathPlanningResult*> pathPlanningResults;
  /// A mapping from character IDs (which can be set externally) to their positions in the 'characters' and 'PathPlanningResults' lists (which always number from 0).
  std::map<int, int> characterVectorPositions;

  /** Finds and returns a pointer to the character with the specified ID.
  * @param id       The ID of the character to find.
  * @return A pointer to the Character object that matches the given ID, or NULL if no such character exists.
  */
  inline Character* getCharacter(int id)
  { 
    std::map<int,int>::iterator findIt = characterVectorPositions.find(id);
    if(findIt == characterVectorPositions.end()) return NULL;
      return &characters[findIt->second];
    }

  /// Adds a character to the simulation, with the specified settings.
  bool Simulator::addCharacter(const Point& pos, short layer, const CharacterSettings& settings, int id)
  {
    Character newCharacter(id, pos, layer, settings);

    // add the character
    characters.push_back(newCharacter);
    // add an empty result
    pathPlanningResults.push_back(NULL);
    // add the ID mapping
    characterVectorPositions.insert(std::pair<int,int>(id, characters.size()-1));
  }
}
```

This class is holding all the characters objects in the simulation.

There is a character class with a method for getting the position:

```
class Character
{
  /** Returns the current 2D position of the character on its current layer.
  * @return The current position of the character.
  */
  inline const Point& getPosition() const { return pos; }
}
```

The Point object contains a X and Y coördinate

And there an API class API_simulator with two methods for getting the position of a character:

```
class API_simulator 
{
  extern "C" EXPORT_API double GetCharacterX(int charid) {
    return simulator->getCharacter(charid)->getPosition().x;
  }

  extern "C" EXPORT_API double GetCharacterY(int charid) {
    return simulator->getCharacter(charid)->getPosition().y;
  }
}
```

When I'm using this API in C# it all works fine. Except when I add a lot of characters to the simulator and I need to get the positions of all the characters. This is taking way to long because every X and Y coordinate of each character has to be found in the tree structure.
Is there a faster way to get the positions of all characters in one time?
Is shared memory the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the map is the bottleneck.  It should be scalable enough, so looking up the information per character via the map should be fast enough even with a couple of thousand characters (which results in 10 to 15 lookups).
However, if you want the coordinates of all characters, you're better off iterating the right vector immediately instead of looking up the offset by the id of each character.

Comment: +1 OP needs to export a set of functions to iterate the maps.

Comment: Do you mean iterating the "std::vector<Character> characters" vector? And if I do that what kind of return type I should use in the API? An array of a struct which contains the ID, X and Y? Is that possible with a C function?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  Just take into account that you need to do some memory management.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the size of the database against in comparison to the size of the input.

If you're going over all the characters in the input (N for input), and try to find them each time in the database map (D for database), then it will cost you **O(NlogD)** operations.

You could decide that you want all the characters in the database, then you could loop over the `characters` vector and that will be **O(D)**.

If the input is much much larger, you could sort the input in a map or vector, and then loop over the database, and compare that to the input. Which is **O(NlogN)** for sorting + **O(DlogN)** for traversing the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. expose a `GetCharacterXY` API method: this would require a single logarithmic-time lookup to get the *(x,y)* position, instead of doing the same lookup twice

   - this still scales as `O(n log n)`, but should be faster
2. try using `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map`, unless you somewhere need your characters sorted by id, as this gives constant-time instead of logarithmic-time lookup

   - this is `O(n)`, but you're still doing a hash lookup for each of the *n* items
3. expose a method that returns all *(id,x,y)* tuples using a linear scan of `characters` instead of multiple lookups, as suggested by Yochai

   - this is `O(n)` and likely to be the fastest (as you do the least superfluous work for each item)